# CN1 Simulator default to screen size

Tags: android, ios, codenameone, simulator

By default, the Codename One simulator displays at the device resolution. If you are using a skin that is larger than your development machine's screen resolution the simulator will be huge and you will need to use Zoom to see the entire screen. The zoom setting does not persist from session to session. It is a real pain to have to re-set the zoom every time the simulator is started. How to set it to automatically default to a zoomed state?

(I am adding this as a Q&A post for the benefit of newer users because this irritated me for several months before I chanced upon the solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unchecking "Scrollable" in the simulator causes it to resize down to fit the window. Unlike zoom, the scrollable setting is persistent between simulator sessions so next time you open it, it will have resized for you.

Remember, however, that a zoomed or scaled down simulator will not be pixel-perfect and will have artifacts due to scaling.